# generating grammars from a language (formal languages and automata theory)

Tags: computer-science, automata, formal-languages

guys I've been working on this assignment for my formal languages class for a couple of days now, and I'm stuck when it comes to generating grammars for a given language. I don't have an example in my textbook similar to this question to follow, so I was hoping anyone could provide an explanation. thank you. [image]

Comment: You might want to notify your teacher that his g-key is broken.

Comment: It took me a while to get @JohannesH 's idea in the comment, if you do so is of course your decision, **but** IMO his answer you really should read carefully and also follow the advice kindly given by him ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem:

- Understand which words are in L.

I actually did this part for you: `L`  defines that any words in that language start with any number (including 0) of `a` or `b`, followed by 1 or more `a`s, follwoed by one `b`, maybe followed by any number of `a`s, followed by the same character it started with (or a repetition of them).

- Read one grammar. See if you can construct words with this grammar that are not in L.
- See if you can find words in L that can not be constructed by this grammar
- If you find either, proceed with the next grammar
- if you find none, the grammar successfully generates L.